# Opening new view from TableViewController

Tags: ios, tableview, segue, viewcontroller, uitableview

I have table view that holds an image and some text. The idea is to open a new view with the specific image and the text displayed when the user clicks the instance in the table view.

I am thinking about solving this simply by having a button overlaying the cell in the table view, but it feels like there should be a simpler built in solution, like a onCellClick(Any sender) function, but I havent found it. Some help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a simple solution and that is to use the UITableViewDelegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
    UIImage *image = cell.imageView.image;

   // here create a new view controller and send these details to your new view controller.
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; //Main = your storyboard name
   DisplayDataViewController *displayDataViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"displayDataViewController"];
  //set data in new view controller before pushing that on top of your navigation controller
  displayDataViewController.imageName = image;
 displayDataViewController.displayStr = cellText;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:displayDataViewController animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Sweet - thank you! I knew there was something :P. I'll try this!

Comment: btw, should i just put in a segue after that to point it at the correct view?

Comment: You don't need any segue. You can simply initiate the desired view controller and push it using the pushViewController method. However, this assumes that your tableView Controller is embedded in a Navigation Controller which you would need anyway if you were to use segue.